# Return Unique Average for column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query in Access to return an average for a survey which is based on a 1-5 answer scale (1 = poor and so on). I can't simply do avg(q1) because the software which creates the surveys and drops the results in the database (autodata expertscan) rates the question a 0 if left unanswered. This skews the results.

I can't do a ...WHERE Q1 > 1 because this eliminates all other questions (each row has a Q1,Q2, etc.).

So, I tried to do a query such as this

```
(SELECT avg(VAL) FROM (SELECT ScannedData.Q1 as VAL FROM ScannedData WHERE ScannedData.Q1 > 1)t) AS AvgOfQ1
```

but the problem with this is the query returns a single value and gives all the rows the same value (e.g. 5.82).

The report being created is grouped by class so I end up with a report that has Class A Q1 5.82, Class B Q1 5.82, Class C Q1 5.82 and so on and on.

To add to this - every single question of this survey needs to be calculated such as this.

In short, how can I get an average for each class grouping with a query such as above.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Added below as requested:

The table contains question results. For each question there is a column with values ranging from 0-6. So, for question 1 on the survey, the column would be named Q1 with values between 1-6. Additionally there is a className column of importance which pertains to the class the survey was related to.

So, I can have a record that looks like this

```
|Q1|Q2|Q3|Q4|ClassName        |
|1 |5 |4 |5 |Asbestos Training|
|3 |4 |0 |6 |Asbestos Training|
|3 |1 |3 |4 |Asbestos Training|
|4 |3 |5 |4 |Microsoft Word   |
|6 |1 |5 |3 |Microsoft Word   |
|0 |2 |5 |1 |Microsoft Word   |
```

With my query above I get results like

Asbestos Training Q1Avg 5.82 (not actual number for above results, just example)
Microsoft Training Q1AVG 5.82

When I would need (using above data, for example)

Asbestos Training Q1Avg 2.33
Microsoft Word Q1Avg 5.00 (0 needs not count because it was skipped and shouldn't skew the results).

I didn't design this database. It's the format the software uses. Everytime we create a survey it drops a new access database.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: Gordon Linoff's solution looks correct, did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want conditional aggregation.  In MS Access this looks like:

```
select avg(iif(Q1 > 0, Q1, NULL)) as Q1_avg,
       avg(iif(Q2 > 0, Q2, NULL)) as Q2_avg,
       avg(iif(Q3 > 0, Q3, NULL)) as Q3_avg       
from ScannedData;
```

If you want this by class, then use `group by`:

```
select class, avg(iif(Q1 > 0, Q1, NULL)) as Q1_avg,
       avg(iif(Q2 > 0, Q2, NULL)) as Q2_avg,
       avg(iif(Q3 > 0, Q3, NULL)) as Q3_avg       
from ScannedData
group by class;
```

Comment: This worked! I was overthinking with the subquery. Thank you. So simple. This leads to the next problem now!